# Turning list elements into a single string

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of lists in this form:

```py
[
  ['3', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '2', ',', '0'],
  ['2', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '0', ',', '0'],
  ['0', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '3', ',', '0']
]
```

I'm trying to put it into a flat list where each element is the contents of each of the sub-list's contents as one string in a new list:

```py
['3,1,0,2,0', '2,1,0,0,0', '0,1,0,3,0']
```

I've tried this:

```
for subs in newBallots:
  for i in subs:
     transferedBallots.append(str(i))
```

But it only makes every character in its own list element:

```py
['3', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '2', ',', '0', '2', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '0', ',', '0', '0', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '3', ',', '0']
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list comprehension should work.
I am assuming the comma in the sublist is often the element you want to remove. Else it could be another list to be checked.

```
my_list=[['3', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '2', ',', '0'], ['2', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '0', ',', '0'], ['0', ',', '1', ',', '0', ',', '3', ',', '0']]
my_list_concat=[",".join([v1 for v1 in v if v1 != ","]) for v in my_list]
```

output:

```
>>> my_list_concat
['3,1,0,2,0', '2,1,0,0,0', '0,1,0,3,0']
```

Comment: I should have used newBallot in the variable name instead of my_list. my bad.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for subs in newBallots:
  transferedBallots.append("".join(subs))
```